# svg icon inside button do not display in the iphone 13 mac simulator

Tags: css, reactjs

Here is CloseIcon svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2">
        <path d="M9 1L1 9M9 9L1 1"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is the code:

```
      <button onClick={onCloseRequested} className={styles.close}>
            <CloseIcon />
       </button>
```

here is the CSS style:

```
.close {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

[image]

It works great in the web browser. However, when I use iPhone 13 simulator on the mac. The svg is no longer there.

If I change the button to div, then the SVG will be displayed. well, I prefer to use the button since it is more semantically correct. Could anyone tell me what is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: You might add a ` .close{-webkit-appearance: none}`  rule to reset any button default styles. iOS safari has quite a lot of these default style especially concerning form elements.